# Point Magento Store View to Subdomain

Tags: magento-1.9

Im attempting to run a 2nd store view on a subdomain, but im just getting a 404 page

Current Website - www.washingtonlighting.co.uk

Subdoamin: showroom.washingtonlighting.co.uk

Im using magento 1.9.0.2 and Cpanel

I have followed this guide to the letter yet it still shows a 404 page.

Guide: https://www.properhost.com/support/kb/30/How-To-Setup-Magento-With-Multiple-Stores-And-Domains

Is there something not included in this guide?

Any questions please fire away.

Thank you,